# How do I get a list of the only group class members of AD group in VBA

Tags: vba, ldap

I am able to loop through nested groups and check if each member is a group or user in a given AD group but as the no of members is more, the more it is taking time to loop.

Group A has 20 members of which 2 are sub groups and rest 18 are users.

Can we obtain only those 2 groups without checking the member class type for each member in the AD object?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.